# low performance on d3-canvas map

Tags: performance, dictionary, d3.js, canvas

I'm using canvas to plot 130,000 d3 points on an OpenStreetMap from a csv file.

The code is based on references from multiple sources, though mainly from:
http://bl.ocks.org/jhubley/25f32b1f123dca4012f1

zooming and moving the map takes a VERY LONG TIME.
Any idea on how to improve performance?

The Entire code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>A D3 Map, points plotted with canvas instead of SVG</title>
<style>

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}

#map{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#points{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}

.layer{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-10;
}

.tile {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 18px;
    z-index: 1000;
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
}   

.credit{
    position:absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
    padding: 9px 20px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.credit a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ddd;
}

div.tooltip {   
    position: absolute;         
    text-align: center;         
    width: 60px;                    
    height: 28px;                   
    padding: 2px;               
    font: 12px sans-serif;      
    background: lightsteelblue; 
    border: 0px;        
    border-radius: 8px;         
    pointer-events: none;           
}

</style>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.geo.tile.v0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div id="map">
        <canvas>
            <div id="points"></div>
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="credit"><p>Data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> Tiles &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a></p></div>
</div>
  <script type='text/javascript'>

/* global variables and initial canvas space set up*/

width = Math.max(960, window.innerWidth),
height = Math.max(500, window.innerHeight),
prefix = prefixMatch(["webkit", "ms", "Moz", "O"]);

d3.csv("ged171 - onlyxy.csv", function(error, dataset) { createMap(dataset) });

var tile = d3.geo.tile()
    .size([width, height]);

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
.scale((1 << 11) / 2 / Math.PI)
.translate([-width / 2, -height / 2]); // just temporary

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scale(projection.scale() * 2 * Math.PI)
    .scaleExtent([1 << 9, 1 << 25])
    .translate(projection([-73.975536, 40.691674]).map(function(x) { return -x; }))
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var container = d3.select("#container")
        .style("width", width + "px")
        .style("height", height + "px")
            .call(zoom)
        .on("mousemove", mousemoved);

var base = d3.select('#map');

var chart = d3.select('canvas')
            .attr("class", "layer")
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

var context = chart.node().getContext('2d');

var locations = d3.select('#points');

var layer = d3.select('.layer');

var info = base.append("div")
    .attr("class", "info");

// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);

zoomed();

function createMap(dataset) {

  var dataBinding = locations.selectAll("points.arc")
    .data(dataset)

        .enter()
      .append("points")
      .classed("arc", true)
      .attr("x", function(d) {return projection([d.y,d.x])[0]})
      .attr("y", function(d) {return projection([d.y,d.x])[1]})
      .attr("radius", 1.5)
      .attr("fillStyle", "rgba(250, 80, 80, 1)")

  drawCanvas();
}

function drawCanvas() {

    var elements = locations.selectAll("points.arc");
    elements.each(function(d) {
    var node = d3.select(this);

    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply';
    context.beginPath();

        context.arc(node.attr("x"), node.attr("y"), node.attr("radius"), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.fillStyle = node.attr("fillStyle");
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
    })
}

function reDraw() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    drawCanvas();
}

function zoomed() {
  var tiles = tile
      .scale(zoom.scale())
      .translate(zoom.translate())
      ();

  projection
      .scale(zoom.scale() / 2 / Math.PI)
      .translate(zoom.translate());


    d3.selectAll("points.arc")
            .attr("x", function(d) {return projection([d.y,d.x])[0]})
      .attr("y", function(d) {return projection([d.y,d.x])[1]})
            reDraw();


  var image = layer
      .style(prefix + "transform", matrix3d(tiles.scale, tiles.translate))
    .selectAll(".tile")
      .data(tiles, function(d) { return d; });

  image.exit()
      .remove();

  image.enter().append("img")
      .attr("class", "tile")
      .attr("src", function(d) { return "http://" + ["a", "b", "c"][Math.random() * 3 | 0] + ".basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + ".png"; })
      .style("left", function(d) { return (d[0] << 8) + "px"; })
      .style("top", function(d) { return (d[1] << 8) + "px"; });
}

function mousemoved() {
  info.text(formatLocation(projection.invert(d3.mouse(this)), zoom.scale()));
}

function matrix3d(scale, translate) {
  var k = scale / 256, r = scale % 1 ? Number : Math.round;
  return "matrix3d(" + [k, 0, 0, 0, 0, k, 0, 0, 0, 0, k, 0, r(translate[0] * scale), r(translate[1] * scale), 0, 1 ] + ")";
}

function prefixMatch(p) {
  var i = -1, n = p.length, s = document.body.style;
  while (++i < n) if (p[i] + "Transform" in s) return "-" + p[i].toLowerCase() + "-";
  return "";
}

function formatLocation(p, k) {
  var format = d3.format("." + Math.floor(Math.log(k) / 2 - 2) + "f");
  return (p[1] < 0 ? format(-p[1]) + " S" : format(p[1]) + " N") + " "
       + (p[0] < 0 ? format(-p[0]) + " W" : format(p[0]) + " E");
}

//onMouseOver test
    var clickFunction = function(e) {
        var mouseX = e.offsetX;
        var mouseY = e.offsetY;
        var col = hiddenContext.getImageData(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1).data;
        var colString = "rgb(" + col[0] + "," + col[1] + "," + col[2] + ")";
        var node = colToCircle[colString];
        if (node) {
            if (focus === node) node = root;
            kids = [node.name];
            if (typeof node.children !== "undefined") {
                for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
                    kids.push(node.children[i].name)
                }
            }
            zoomToCanvas(node);
        }
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment

Unfortunately it didn't improve performance and the dots also didn't update their location when dragging. :(

Comment: You have a lot of points with each drag/zoom you repaint *all* the points in the canvas. I wrote a plugin https://github.com/cyrilcherian/Leaflet-Fullcanvas
which uses quad tree so that only visible points are redraw in zoom in.(but still not good enough)

Or if you can cluster all points together then may be you can use elastic search https://github.com/cyrilcherian/million-points-on-map In this i managed to show a million points. Thought of sharing this info here.

Comment: As I noted in my—now obsolete and therefore deleted—comment, providing a working demo showing the effect would be of much help!